# Split text into tokens on different rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, csv, split, token, pos-tagger

I am new to this but I am trying to split text in a pandas dataframe into individual rows consisting of each tokens of the text and also its respective POS and TAG. For example:

```
            Text
   1        Police officers arrest teen.
   2        Man agrees to help.
```

What i am trying to achieve here is:

```
Sentence#  Token     POS   Tag
   1       Police    NNS   B-NP
           officers  NNS   I-NP
           arrest    VBP   B-VP
           teen      NN    B-NP
   2       Man       NNP   B-NP
           agrees    VBZ   B-VP
           to        TO    B-VP
           help      VB    B-VP
```

Comment: What are you counting as a token? For example, what if a word ends with a colon/semicolon? Do you want the colon/semicolon to be treated as a separate token?

Comment: @oda in this case semicolon/colon and "." will be replaced with " " spaces before tokenizing the text. That reminds me i have to edit my question and remove the "."

Comment: @oda Yes! thank you very much! is it also possible to add the tree tags? like the B-NP, I-NP, B-VP?

Comment: @oda What do you mean by random things in my desired output? I'm looking for the Tag to be  for example Police officers arrest teen -> B-NP I-NP B-VP B-NP if im not mistaken that is the correct tree tag im not too sure myself

Comment: Were you able to sort everything out?

Comment: @oda Yes thank you very much! was able to find the grammar vocab for the tags for the NP , VP and PP.

Comment: Woo! Glad to hear! Out of interest, would it be possible to share how you got the tags (NP, VP and PP) right? If it is too much don't sweat it!

Comment: @oda I'll be happy to share it, I can't quite remember exactly where I got it from but here's the grammar vocab that I manage to acquire not sure if its exactly accurate. Might be from nltk.org but I could be mistaken

grammar = 
"""NP: {<DT>*<JJ>*<JJR>*<JJS>*<NNP>*<NNPS>*<PDT>*<POS>*<CC>*<CD>*<NNS>*<PRP>*<PRP$>*<RB>*<RBR>*<RBS>*<RP>*<WDT>*<WP>*<WP$>*<WRB>*<NN>*}
    VP: {<VBD>*<VBN>*<TO>*<VB>*<VBG>*<MD>*}
    PP: {<IN>|<TO>}"""

Comment: @oda Out of curiosity, is it possible to also add the Named Entity Tags? B-PER, I-PER (Person) , B-LOC, I-LOC (Location)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nltk` module can help you do what you want. This code makes use of `nltk` to create a new DataFrame with similar output to your desired output. In order to get matching tags to your desired output, you will likely need to supply your own chunk parser. I am no expert in POS and IOB tagging.

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, tree2conlltags, RegexpParser

# orig data
d = {'Text': ["Police officers arrest teen.", "Man agrees to help."]}
# orig DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

# new data
new_d = {'Sentence': [], 'Token': [], 'POS': [], 'Tag': []}

# grammar taken from nltk.org
grammar = r"NP: {<[CDJNP].*>+}"
parser = RegexpParser(grammar)

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    temp = tree2conlltags(parser.parse(pos_tag(word_tokenize(row["Text"]))))
    new_d['Token'].extend(i[0] for i in temp)
    new_d['POS'].extend(i[1] for i in temp)
    new_d['Tag'].extend(i[2] for i in temp)
    new_d['Sentence'].extend([idx + 1] * len(temp))

# new DataFrame
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data = new_d)

print(f"***Original DataFrame***\n\n {df}\n")
print(f"***New DataFrame***\n\n {new_df}")
```

Output:

```
***Original DataFrame***

                            Text
0  Police officers arrest teen.
1           Man agrees to help.

***New DataFrame***

    Sentence     Token  POS   Tag
0         1    Police  NNP  B-NP
1         1  officers  NNS  I-NP
2         1    arrest  VBP     O
3         1      teen   NN  B-NP
4         1         .    .     O
5         2       Man   NN  B-NP
6         2    agrees  VBZ     O
7         2        to   TO     O
8         2      help   VB     O
9         2         .    .     O
```

Note after doing a `pip` install of `nltk`, before the above code can run, you will likely have to call `nltk.download` a few times. The error message you get should tell you what to execute. For example, you will likely need to execute this

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('punkt')
>>> nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
```